# Why isn't `setModel()` defined in my goog.ui.Component?

Tags: google-closure, google-closure-library

I made a subclass of goog.ui.Component:

```
/**
 * Renders the bottom pane.
 * @param {!myapp.Entity} entity An entity.
 * @param {goog.dom.DomHelper=} opt_domHelper Optional DOM helper.
 * @constructor
 * @extends {goog.ui.Component}
 */
myapp.BottomPane = function(entity, opt_domHelper) {
  goog.base(this, opt_domHelper);
  this.setModel(entity);
}
goog.inherits(myapp.BottomPane, goog.ui.Component);
```

However, when I run my javascript, Chrome Console notes that `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'setModel'`. I set a breakpoint and realized that, indeed, my `myapp.BottomPane` instance lacked a `setModel` method in the prototype chain. This is odd since the documentation notes that all components have this method: http://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn/docs/class_goog_ui_Component.html

Why does my `goog.ui.Component` lack a `setModel` method? I know that the call to `goog.base(this, opt_domHelper);` is working because my object has a DOM helper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to reproduce the error `Object #<Object> has no method 'setModel'` by executing the constructor `myapp.BottomPane` without using the `new` keyword.

```
var bottomPane = myapp.BottomPane({id: 'my_id'}); // Results in error.
```

Make sure to use `new` to create instances.

```
var bottomPane = new myapp.BottomPane({id: 'my_id'}); // Okay
```